# Generate every possible spacing within a specified string?

Tags: python, bash, loops, math, awk

I have strings of morse code with spaces removed, all of equal length.

Say one for example is `..--.---..`,

I want to generate every possible solution on separate lines.

Ie, `. . - - . - - - . .`, `.. - - .- --. .`, `..- -.- - -. .`, etc.

What's a good, efficient way to do this? I'm terrible with this kind of thing and I'm stumped.

Comment: Bash is almost certainly the wrong tool for this. If the strings are in a file, permuting it with e.g. Awk should not be hard; though a modern scripting language like Python might be a better choice if you don't have any preference as to where to start.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to show some sort of effort - if not your own code attempt then at least what you searched for, what you found, and what trouble you are having with applying those search results to your problem.

Comment: I used to ask about this in interviews. If it's an XY question for "how can I find all possible English words this string can represent?", I would suggest going backwards from an English dictionary instead. That way it won't be `O(2^n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one in awk. I was just playing around with awk binary conversions when I saw this question and decided to try something. It runs from *i=0* to *2<sup>(length(morse)-1)</sup>-1*, converts the *i* to binary and replaces all 1s with  spaces and 0s with nulls, for example:

```
morse=-.-
length(morse)=3 -> 2^(3-1)-1=3
runs 0..3
0==00 -> -0.0- -> -.-
1==01 -> -0.1- -> -. -
2==10 -> -1.0- -> - .-
3==11 -> -1.1- -> - . -
```

Script:

```
$ echo -..- |
  awk '
  function tobin(d,l) {
    r=""
    while(d) {
        r=d%2r
        d=int(d/2)
    }
    return sprintf("%0" l "d",r)
} 
{
    n=split($0,a,"")
    for(i=0;i<=2^(length-1)-1;i++) {
        split(tobin(i,length-1),b,"")
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            printf "%s%s",a[j],(b[j]?" ":(j==n?ORS:""))
    }
}'
```

Output:

```
-..-
-.. -
-. .-
-. . -
- ..-
- .. -
- . .-
- . . -
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in pure bash, it could get tricky. The idea is to make use of the brace expansion which will take care of all possibilities.

```
$ a='..--'
$ [[ $a =~ ${a//?/(.)} ]] && b=${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1} && eval printf "%s\\\n" ${b// /\{,\" \"\}})
```

**How does it work?**

The idea is essentially transform

```
'..--'
```

into

```
.{," "}.{," "}-{," "}-
```

and let bash use brace-expansion to make all combinations.

1. **`[[ $a =~ ${a//?/(.)} ]]`** The bash test will attempt to match the regular expression `${a//?/(.)}` which resembles `(.)(.)(.)(.)`. It will store all matches in the variable `BASH_REMATCH`
2. **`b=${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}`** The element of `BASH_REMATCH` with index 0 is the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression.  The element of `BASH_REMATCH` with index `n` is the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression. Hence we are only interested in all parts except the first:

   ```
   $ [[ $a =~ ${a//?/(.)} ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[*]}
   ..-- . . - -
   $ [[ $a =~ ${a//?/(.)} ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}
   . . - -
   ```
3. **`${b// /\{,\" \"\}}`** This substitutes all spaces with `{," "}`. This will allow us to use brace expansion which we will need to evaluate with `eval`

   ```
   $ a='..--'
   $ [[ $a =~ ${a//?/(.)} ]]
   $ b=${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}
   $ echo "${b// /\{,\" \"\}}"
   .\{," "\}.\{," "\}-\{," "\}-
   ```